# NoReverseMatch at ...... in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-queryset, django-q

I am working on a blog site where you can search for posts by using searching with keywords (basically a normal searchbar).

I have imported Q from django.db.models

The view I created:

```
def search(request):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    query =  request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(overview__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()

    context = {
        'queryset': queryset,
    }
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', context)
```

The urlpattern:

```
path('search/', search, name='search-results'),
```

The form itself:

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" class="search-form">{% csrf_token %}
              <button type="submit" class="submit"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <span class="icon icon-search"></span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Type a keyword and hit enter">
                </div>
              </form>
```

When I want to access the page to which I have put this form in, it says: 
Reverse for 'search' not found. 'search' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Below it also shows this:

```
1   <!DOCTYPE html>
2   <html lang="en">
3   
4   {% include 'head.html' %}
5   
6   <body>
7       
8       {% include 'header.html' %}
9   
10      {% block content %}
```

I have tried adding/removing csrf_token and the submit button, but the result is always the same. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the form is a part of the `head.html`. You don't need the `csrf_token` since it's not a `post` form.

In `urlpatterns`, change your url entry to:

```py
path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
```

At the template, `action="{% url 'search' %}"` refers to the name of the url ... you could also add `role='search'` attribute to your form. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

When you use `{% url '' %}` tag, it try to find url based on url names. You must use url names inside it . Please change `{% url 'search' %}` with `{% url 'search-results' %}`